# Powershell: How to output folder name, lastwritetime and folder size in one line?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I want to out put folder name, lastwritetime and folder size,  how can i combine both of the results in to one line?

For folder name and lastwritetime:

```
get-item "\\server-01\Y$\Server1" | select name,lastwritetime
```

For folder size:

```
$folder = (Get-ChildItem "\\server-01\Y$\Server1" -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
$size = "{0:N2}" -f ($folder.sum / 1024MB) + " GB"
```

I need output format like this:

```
Name       LastWriteTime       Size
Server1    2014-05-05          55G
```

Also how to make a loop of running this function through a list of PCs?

Any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select-Object` will be your friend here:

`foreach ($c in (get-content .\Servers.txt)) 
    { Get-Childitem \\$c\y$\mydirectory | select-object @{l="Name" ; e = {$c}},Lastwritetime,@{l="Size" ; e={(Get-childitem -recurse | measure-object length -sum).sum}} }`

But you could also do yourself a favor and add a function like get-foldersize to your profile or to a standard tools module.

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Get-FolderSize-b3d317f5

Comment: I guess that looks like gibberish if you aren't already familiar with the Label/Expression syntax...  This article talks about it a bit: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692794.aspx

Answer (score 2):

For Folder name and lastwritetime:

`Get-Item $Path | Where-Object { $_.BaseName ,$_.LastWriteTime}`

For folder size:

```
$log="C:\log.txt"

$Path = "C:\Test"
$Items = Get-ChildItem $Path  | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | Sort-Object
foreach ($f in $Items){
   $itemSum = Get-ChildItem ("$Path\" + $f.Name) | Select-Object @{ l="Path" ; e = {$f}},LastWriteTime,@{l="Size" ; e={((Get-childitem -recurse | measure-object length -sum).Sum /1KB)}}

   }
```

Enjoy!!

FYI

[Query Folder tree for Size and export to a log on a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280997/query-folder-tree-for-size-and-export-to-a-log-on-a-server])

Answer (score 1):

Here's a true one-liner with some formatting.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Force|ForEach {"{0,-30} {1,-30} {2:N2}MB" -f $_.Name, $_.LastWriteTime, ((Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse|Measure-Object  -Property Length -Sum  -ErrorAction Stop).Sum/1MB)}
```

Result:

[image]